# How to find the number of unique followers of two users in a large Twitter graph?

Tags: r, networking, matrix, twitter, graph

I'm trying to find the number of unique followers of two users (union(followers A, followers B)) in twitter.
I used the following code and it works perfectly fine for small graphs.

```
library(igraph)
library(Matrix) 
mat<-matrix(c("A","A","C","B","C","D","H","F","F","I","I","C","D","D","D","E","E‌​","F","E","G","F","G"),ncol=2) 
mat<-as.data.frame(mat)
graph<-graph.data.frame(mat)
undirected_graph<-graph.data.frame(mat,directed=FALSE)
A<-get.adjacency(graph)
D<-colSums(A)
B<-matrix(D,ncol=length(D),nrow=length(D)) 
#unique followers of two selected nodes 
unique<-B+t(B)-t(A)%*%A
runique<-unique-get.adjacency(undirected_graph)
```

Now I want to use this code for larger graphs.The code can easily create the adjacency matrix, but when it comes to matrix B, I run out of memory.
I tried the following code:

```
B<-Matrix(D,ncol=length(D),nrow=length(D),sparse=T)
```

But I still have the same problem. Could you please help me on this problem?

Answer (score 0):

`unique` can be computed without computing `B` like this:

```
unique <- t(D + t(D - crossprod(A)))
```